# Select favourite videos - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

In my website, you can check out what videos has been liked by an user.

This is the code...

**PHP**

```
     public static function VideosFavoritos($user){
        $sql = "SELECT id, titulo, directorio, imagen, usuario_id FROM video INNER JOIN videos_likes ON videos_likes.video_id = video.id AND videos_likes.id_canal = '$user'";
        $resultado = self::Conexion($sql);
        $videos = array();

        if(isset($resultado)){
            $row = $resultado->fetch();
            while($row != null){
                $videos[] = new Videos($row);
                $row = $resultado->fetch();
            }
        }
        return $videos;
    }

    public static function MostrarVideosFavoritos($user){
        $videos = self::VideosFavoritos($user);

        if(empty($videos)){
            print "<h4>Este usuario no tiene videos favoritos</h4>";
        } else {
            foreach($videos as $video) {
                print "<div class='video_main_container'>";
                    print "<div class='video_container'>";
                        print "<div class='video_thumb'><a data-id='".$video->getID()."'><img src='include/images/videos/video-thumb.png' alt='' /></a></div>";
                        print "<div class='video_info'>";
                            print "<p class='title'>".$video->getTitulo()."</p>";
                            print "<p class='usuario'>".$video->getUsuario()."</p>";
                        print "</div>";
                    print "</div>";
                print "</div>";
            }
        }
    }
```

**MYSQL IMAGES**

**video table** = [LINK](https://gyazo.com/fe1c2d612af1cf61cd4226033272e4c8)

**videos liked table** = [LINK](https://gyazo.com/dc326c2da4ce68c775c1021a4d1b6361)

The sql is not well done... How can I do it for printing the videos that an user likes?

**UPDATED**

I thnk I got it by myself...

Comment: Shouldn't be `$videos = self::Videos($user);` replaced by `$videos = self::VideosFavoritos($user);`?

Comment: Your query already appears to be doing this...what is the problem?